# How sort data by colors in ruby script

Tags: ruby, colors

I want to sort data generated by wash with colors an power (dBm), the output of wash data is like this

```
 SSID   BSSID                     power      Canal
1 MyBox 00:11:22:33:44:55         dBm -45    Canal: 11
2 OtherBox 00:11:22:33:44:88      dBm -65    Canal: 6
3 OtherOtherBox 00:11:22:33:66:88 dBm -82    Canal: 1
4 ...
```

Examples of what i want:

```
If the dBm is between -0 and -60 must be in green
If the dBm is between -60 and -80 must be in orange
If the dBm is between -80 and -100 must be in red
```

The code im using:

```
def select_point_to_crack(access_points, wlan_iface_name)
  access_points = access_points.sort_by { |access_point| access_point[:power] }
  puts "Enter a number (between 0 y #{access_points.length - 1}):"
  access_points.each_with_index do |access_point, idx|
    puts "#{idx}. #{access_point[:essid]} #{access_point[:vendor]} #{access_point[:bssid]} #{access_point[:power]}dB Canal: #{access_point[:channel]}"
  end
```

The networks are already sort by dBm but no with color.

How can i do that with ruby ?

Comment: Are you sorting or categorizing?

Comment: Tip: Use ranges, like `-60..0`

Comment: You have to 1) read the data, 2) extract each line's dBm value, 3) sort by that value and 4) print the lines in different colors. Please show what you have so far so we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: I just edited my question i hope this is more clear

Comment: Color in a terminal is created by so-called [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g. `puts "\e[31mred\e[32mgreen\e[33myellow\e[0mnormal"`. There are also gems which wrap these in nice Ruby methods, e.g. [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize).